# Trying to allocate and set to 0 a matrix dynamically in C, but I can't get the set to 0 part to work

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I have this matrix initialization function I need: I can generate it without any problems but can't initialize all its values to 0, neither with `calloc` or via looping on the matrix elements.

The function is as follows:

```
int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX) {
  int **locMTX = malloc(r * sizeof(int *)), i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    locMTX[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
      locMTX[i][j] = 0;
  *MTX = locMTX;

  return 1;
}
```

If needed for context, the entire code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX);
void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX);
void freeMTX(int r, int **MTX);

int main(void) {
  int NBits = 4, NNumbers = 2 ^ NBits, **MTXResults;
  initMTX(NNumbers, NBits, &MTXResults);
  // code
  printMTX(NNumbers, NBits, MTXResults);
  freeMTX(NNumbers, MTXResults);
}

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX) {
  int **locMTX = malloc(r * sizeof(int *)), i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    locMTX[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
      locMTX[i][j] = 0;
  *MTX = locMTX;
  return 1;
}

void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
      printf("%d ", MTX[i][r]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void freeMTX(int r, int **MTX) {
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    free(MTX[i]);
  free(MTX);
}
```

I thought I grasped such a thing well by now, but it turns out it is not the case, so I've been stuck for a while.
If possible I would appreciate also knowing where the problem is when using `calloc` too.

Comment: `printf("%d ", MTX[i][r]);` <-- HERE

Comment: `2 ^ NBits` is probably not what you want. `^` is bitwise ***XOR***. Use shift instead.

Comment: The function always returns `1`. Instead of grappling with a **three-star pointer** argument return a two-star pointer instead.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What's the problem with that printf?

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, but I originally intended to use the return value 0 for NULL pointer from malloc as "training" for debug, but I removed for readability, that's why it's there

Comment: You could `return NULL` in the case of error.

Comment: I don't see the problem with your `initMTX` function. I ran your code and it printed all zeroes.

Comment: @Barmar One of the indices is not like the other.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I see now. Why don't you just come out and say what the typo is, instead of making it a challenge?

Comment: `MTX[i][r]` should be `MTX[i][j]`

Comment: Note that leak-free error recovery in the `initMTX()` function is quite intricate, and the code involves a lot of allocations.  You could simplify the allocation, error recovery and release by allocating a single block of `r * c * sizeof(MTX[0][0])` bytes and then assigning the pointers to appropriate positions within that block of memory.  Then you have only two allocations to release and only one to release if the allocation of the second block fails.

Comment: @Barmar First-hand experience is more valuable than second-hand experience. Me finding the typo is good, OP finding the typo is better. OP finding the typo without me pointing at the line is the best, but that would mean telling them "use yer blessed debugger", and I'm sick and tired of this phrase.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Typo questions serve no purpose. Just point it out, vote to close, and wait for the Roomba to delete it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can do that, but then all your code that uses the matrix will have to calculate the row-major index. You can hide that in a macro, but this is simple enough.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this makes sense, thank you. May I ask you confirmation of what follows? How I allocated it does not necessarily allocate contiguous memory line by line, while in your case of course it does, right?

Comment: @Barmar: I think you misunderstood my proposal.  There would still be two allocations, one for the array of pointers, and one for the actual data.  And the array of pointers would be initialized so that `locMtx[n]` points to the nth row of data.  You'd still use the double-subscript notation to access the array values.  The row-major calculation is done in the initialization.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes sense. I've probably seen it in some questions/answers, and never appreciated the value.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixes the bugs in the code in the question (most notably the typo `MTX[i][r]` becomes `MTX[i][j]`), and implements `freeMTX()`.  It also includes the code to recover from a memory allocation failure while creating the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX);
void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX);
void freeMTX(int r, int **MTX);

int main(void)
{
    int NBits = 4;
    int NNumbers = 16;
    int **MTXResults;

    if (initMTX(NNumbers, NBits, &MTXResults))
    {
        printMTX(NNumbers, NBits, MTXResults);
        freeMTX(NNumbers, MTXResults);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate %dx%d matrix\n", NBits, NNumbers);
}

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX)
{
    int **locMTX = malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    if (locMTX == 0)
        return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        locMTX[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
        if (locMTX[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(locMTX[j]);
            free(locMTX);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            locMTX[i][j] = 0;
    }

    *MTX = locMTX;
    return 1;
}

void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", MTX[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void freeMTX(int r, int **MTX)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        free(MTX[i]);
    free(MTX);
}
```

This code uses the simpler, two allocation scheme outlined in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545645/trying-to-allocate-and-set-to-0-a-matrix-dynamically-in-c-but-i-cant-get-the-s?noredirect=1#comment129874817_73545645) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545645/trying-to-allocate-and-set-to-0-a-matrix-dynamically-in-c-but-i-cant-get-the-s?noredirect=1#comment129877661_73545645):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX);
void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX);
void freeMTX(int **MTX);

int main(void)
{
    int NBits = 4;
    int NNumbers = 16;
    int **MTXResults;

    if (initMTX(NNumbers, NBits, &MTXResults))
    {
        printMTX(NNumbers, NBits, MTXResults);
        freeMTX(MTXResults);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate %dx%d matrix\n", NBits, NNumbers);
}

int initMTX(int r, int c, int ***MTX)
{
    int **locMTX = malloc(r * sizeof(locMTX[0]));
    if (locMTX == 0)
        return 0;
    int *data = malloc(r * c * sizeof(locMTX[0][0]));
    if (data == 0)
    {
        free(locMTX);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        locMTX[i] = data + i * c;
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            locMTX[i][j] = 0;
    }

    *MTX = locMTX;
    return 1;
}

void printMTX(int r, int c, int **MTX)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%d ", MTX[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void freeMTX(int **MTX)
{
    free(MTX[0]);
    free(MTX);
}
```

The freeing code is much simpler, as is the error recovery while creating the matrix — mainly because there are only two allocations that can fail.